# Angular 2 - Return inside `then` - async

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm having a usecase where it would be great if it was possible to somehow return the value retrieved in `.then()`.

Let me show you why and what and want.

In almost every API call I want to send along the `API_KEY` and the `DEVICE_ID`. Now for UX reasons these values are wihin an object called `user` in the Native Storage (will be Secure Storage later on).

The thing here is, that my `headers` will be the empty headers created on the first line. This makes sense since `.then()` will be async.

```
getUserHeaders(): Headers {
        let headers: Headers = new Headers();
        let user = NativeStorage.getItem("user").then(
            data => {
                headers.append('API_KEY', data.json().apiKey);
                headers.append('DEVICE_ID', data.json().deviceId);
            },
            error => {
                console.log("error");
                headers.append('API_KEY', 'TEST');
                headers.append('DEVICE_ID', 'TEST');
            }
        );
        return headers;
    }
```

Now what I want to do is on every call have: f.e.

```
this.http.get('someUrl', { headers: this.getUserHeaders() } ).map(..);
```

My question is, how can I return the headers either from within the `data` and `error` block or should I try a totally different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. Once async, async forever. There's nothing you can do about it.

Just return the `headers` from within `.then(..)` and return the Promise

```
getUserHeaders(): Headers {
    let headers: Headers = new Headers();
    return = NativeStorage.getItem("user").then(
        data => {
            headers.append('API_KEY', data.json().apiKey);
            headers.append('DEVICE_ID', data.json().deviceId);
            return headers;
        },
        error => {
            console.log("error");
            headers.append('API_KEY', 'TEST');
            headers.append('DEVICE_ID', 'TEST');
            return headers;
        }
    );
}
```

then the caller can use it like

```
this.getUserHeaders().then(headers => /* doSoemthingWithHeaders */)
```

Comment: so then it would become something like `this.getUserHeaders().then(headers => this.http.get('someUrl', { headers: headers } ).map(...) )` right?

Comment: but that means my API calls will return a promise of an observable? :O

Comment: You can also use an observable for the header and use `mergeMap` or some other operator. Perhaps observable operators support `Promise` as well (don't know I'm not using them myself).

Comment: ok ill open another question for the observable usecase with a detailed explanation